# Como definir um cabeçalho de uma requisição GET em GoLang

Tags: api, http-request, golang, http-headers

Estou tentando fazer da GoLang minha primeira linguagem mid-high level, porém estou com alguns problemas. Não consigo definir um cabeçalho pra uma requisição GET externa de jeito nenhum, procurei na documentação, fóruns e a única coisa que achei foi pra definir um cabeçalho de resposta (para criação de API's). No meu caso, preciso definir um cabeçalho pra uma requisição GET pra uma determinada API.

Na documentação dessa API, diz que a autenticação é feita através do cabeçalho

```
Authentication: "TOKEN"
```

Tentei de diversas formas. Atualmente meu código está assim, algum bom tradutor ou conhecedor da linguagem pra me explicar como seto esse header?

```
func get() {
    API := "www.google.com"
    TOKEN := "abcdefg"

    resp, err := http.Get(API)
    resp.Header.Set("Authentication", TOKEN)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    defer resp.Body.Close()
    bodyBytes, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)

    bodyString := string(bodyBytes)
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", bodyString)

}

func main() {
    get()
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```golang
resp, err := http.Get(API)
```

Não tem como alterar o cabeçalho com `Get`, ele faz a requisição imediatamente e usa os valores *default* do pacote [`http`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http).

---

O que você precisa criar é uma *custom request*, usando a função [`NewRequest`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#NewRequest).

```golang
req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, API, nil)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Depois alteramos o cabeçalho de `req`, e fazemos a requisição com [`Do`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client.Do)

```golang
req.Header.Set("Authorization", "Token " + TOKEN)

resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

---

```golang
func get() {
    API := "https://www.google.com" // Você tem que colocar o protocol scheme da URL 
    TOKEN := "abcdefg"

    req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, API, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    req.Header.Set("Authorization", "Token " + TOKEN)

    resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    defer resp.Body.Close()
    bodyBytes, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)

    bodyString := string(bodyBytes)
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", bodyString)
}
```

---

**OBS**.: `http.DefaultClient` é o cliente HTTP padrão do pacote, porém ele não define um *timeout* para as requisições. Se o servidor da API, por exemplo, estiver fora do ar ou com outros problemas a sua aplicação pode ficar travada aguardando a resposta. Então é recomendado criar os seus próprios [`http.Client`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client)'s.

Leia mais sobre:

- [The complete guide to Go net/http timeouts](https://blog.cloudflare.com/the-complete-guide-to-golang-net-http-timeouts/)
- [Make resilient Go net/http servers using timeouts](https://ieftimov.com/post/make-resilient-golang-net-http-servers-using-timeouts-deadlines-context-cancellation/)
- [Don’t use Go’s default HTTP client (in production)](https://medium.com/@nate510/don-t-use-go-s-default-http-client-4804cb19f779)

Comment: Entendi que o GET não é "parametravel", mas mesmo editando o code ainda está dando erro de autenticação. Tenho certeza que é em relação as Headers da Request pois no JS está funcionando e recebendo os dados da API de forma correta, com o mesmo token, mesma API, et cetera.

Comment: Poderia postar o link da doc da API? E a mensagem de erro tambem.

Comment: {"message":"As credenciais de autenticação não foram fornecidas ou estão inválidas.

Esta mensagem de erro é da API, pois testei no JS/php/curl usando o token certo/errado. É o retorno 403 da api.

Comment: @DashaDelas tente setar o header dessa forma: `req.Header.Set("Authorization", "Token " + TOKEN)` .

Answer (score 1):

Você deve fazer o set do header antes de fazer o request.

Segue um exemplo:

```
API_URL := "https://www.google.com.br"
request, _ := http.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, API_URL, nil)

request.Header.Set("X-APPLICATION-TOKEN", "Abc_213")

REQUEST_TIMEOUT := 30
client := &http.Client{
    Timeout:   time.Duration(REQUEST_TIMEOUT) * time.Second,
}
response, err := client.Do(request)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalln(err)
}

defer response.Body.Close()
//fazer leitura do body da requisição
```

Em meu exemplo estou utilizando a função `NewRequest` do package [http](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#NewRequest).

---

Em sua aplicação caso utilize certificados auto-assinados, pode haver problemas para fazer a requisição.

Para resolver este problema, você deve criar um http.Transport e remover a verificação de certificados confiáveis, utilizando a opção `InsecureSkipVerify` setando o valor true.

Segue um exemplo:

```
import (
"crypto/tls"
//...
)

tr := &http.Transport{
    TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true},
}
// depois utilizar na instanciação do http.Client
client := &http.Client{
    Transport: tr,
    Timeout:   time.Duration(REQUEST_TIMEOUT) * time.Second,
}
```

Comment: Continua dando erro, tenho 90% de certeza que é nos Headers, pois a API exige que o Header Authentication seja o Token gerado pelo site. Testei com Node e PHP e ambos rodaram liso!

Comment: Pode estar faltando algum header , tipo application/json. Poderia mostrar como está fazendo utilizando o `curl`, caso consiga fazer um request com sucesso?

Comment: Outro problema que já passei é se tiver utilizando https com certificado auto-assinado, vou editar para conter a informação.

Comment: Publiquei um novo omentário, com explicações atualizadas sobre.

Answer (score 0):

Bom, estou fazendo a mesma requisição com NodeJS + node-fetch e está retornando 200 com os dados da API, usando o seguinte código:

```
const headers = {
  method: 'get',
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Token ${token}`,
  }
}

fetch(url, headers)
```

Como não declarei mais nenhum header a não ser a Authorization (sim, eu tinha errado essa parte, estava usando Authentication, mas mesmo corrigindo, dá 403.

Meu code em GO

```
req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", URL, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    req.Header.Set("Authorization", TOKEN)
    resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    defer resp.Body.Close()
    bodyBytes, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)

    // Convert response body to string
    bodyString := string(bodyBytes)
    fmt.Print(bodyString)
```

Sendo:

```
TOKEN: correto! O mesmo do JS (ctrl + ctrl v milhões de vezes)
```

```
URL: Usada com o protocolo e correta, pois entra diretamente acessada pelo browser, requerida pelo cURL, PHP, NODE...
```

Comment: Aqui não mostra como está definido o seu token, em golang ele deveria ser: `req.Header.Set("Authorization", "Token "+TOKEN)`,

Comment: Meu deus, não acredito! FUNCIONOU

Comment:  hehehe, resolvido.

Answer (score 0):

Como as duas respostas me ajudaram, deixo aqui a solução para o meu problema, caso alguém esteja buscando pelo mesmo,

Primeiro de tudo, estava usando o método errado de HTTP, pois o GET não tem headers setáveis. Então, ao invés de `http.Get` tive que usar `http.NewRequest`, como explicou usuário Suriyel.

Então, após isso, o problema ainda continuou, e a solução dada pelo usuário Danizavtz foi usar:

```
req.Header.Set("Authorization", "Token "+TOKEN)
```

ao invés de

```
req.Header.Set("Authorization", TOKEN)
```